# could not insert the data to database

Tags: php, insert

Something went wrong with my code. The insert code does not work. Can someone tell me what went wrong? The code is supposed to insert the person fbid `name` and `email` to my database when the users click a button, however nothing appears in my database.

```
<?php
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
include_once 'mysqli.connect.php';
include_once 'fbmain.php';

if($me){
    $fbid= $facebook->api('/me');
    $fbme = $fbid['id'];
    $fbName = $fbid['name'] ;  
    $fbEmail = $fbid['email'];
}
if (isset($_POST['submit']) ){
    mysqli_query("INSERT members SET fbId='$fbme',name='$fbName', email ='$fbEmail'" );
}
?>
<html>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="image" src="../images/buy.png" name="submit" width="60"height="30" />
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "does not work" mean?  Did you get any error messages?

Comment: Where does `$me` come from? What happens when there is no `$me`, but the form is submitted?

Comment: oh $me is a fb api that i am calling . and i got no error messages .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really check for errors to find out what is going on if something doesn't work (as expected).

That being said:

[mysqli_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php) takes 2 required parameter, `link` and `query`, but you only supplied the `query`.

Another thing: even if you would have done that your query still is invalid. It should be:

```
"INSERT INTO members (fbId, name, email) values ('$fbme', '$fbName', '$fbEmail')"
```

Also note that you check for the variable `$me` (which as you stated is coming from FaceBook). So my question is what will happen when FB is down or whatever and you try to submit the form? You will still try to run the query even though the required info isn't there.

So what I would do is the folllowing:

```
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "dbname");

if($me){
    $fbid= $facebook->api('/me');
    $fbme = $fbid['id'];
    $fbName = $fbid['name'] ;  
    $fbEmail = $fbid['email'];

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO members (fbId, name, email) values ('$fbme', '$fbName', '$fbEmail')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
}
```

As an alternative you could also use prepared statements. One of the benefits of using prepared statements is that it prevents most SQLinjection vulnerabilities. Using prepared statements would look something like this:

```
/* Prepare a statement */
$stmt = mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO table (col1, col2 ...) VALUES (?, ? ...) WHERE uID=?");

/* Bind parameters */
$stmt->bind_param('is', $a, $b ...);  // <-- i=int, s=string, etc. etc.

/* Set parameters */    
$a = $fbMe;
$b = $fbName;
...                // <-- etc. etc.

/* Execute your statement */
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: How does this answer OP's question?

Comment: As Barry Chapman pointed out, the syntax was incorrect. While the guts of the question was the syntax, I thought it would help to show OP another way to achieve the same result (without too much hassle and some extra benefits). I would have used this code to solve OP's problem but I dunno, was it a waste of time?   :-|   ?

Comment: @OP Why are you doing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` instead of `if (isset($_POST['submit']))`?

Comment: Hey hey, thanks PeeHaa! I still consider myself new and learning so it's fun to put my own knowledge to the test. Esp. gratifying to get validated by the pros. ;-) While on this topic I also want to mention to OP; Once you start getting the hang of basic mySQLi statements, check out Idiorm/Paris. They are really cool light weight ORM and active record database toolkits. If I had enough stackoverflow points I'd create a new tag for Paris. Idiorm has one but these tools really deserve more discussion and acknowledgment. http://j4mie.github.com/idiormandparis/

Answer (score 1):

```
mysqli_query("INSERT members SET fbId='$fbme',name='$fbName', email ='$fbEmail'" ); is wrong, you need:

'INSERT INTO members ( 'id', 'name' .... ) VALUES ( [value1], [value2] )'
```

Comment: To clarify, your syntax is incorrect. See http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_insert.asp

Comment: +1 @user1175105 You're mixing update and insert syntax. P.S. Please check for errrors

Answer (score 0):

as the previous user has stated your insert query is incorrect... you could use

```
mysql_error()
```

to print the exact error message for your reference

Comment: i have change according to some of the suggested answers still it didnlt went in. the codes i tried :

Comment: <?php
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
 include_once 'mysqli.connect.php';
 include_once 'fbmain.php';

     
if($me){
     $fbid= $facebook->api('/me');
     $fbme = $fbid['id'];
     $fbName = $fbid['name'] ;  
     $fbEmail = $fbid['email'];
     }
   if (isset($_POST) ){
 
 
  mysqli_query("INSERT INTO Members(name, email, fbid)
VALUES ($fbName, $fbEmail, $fbme)");

  }
  ?>
<html>
<form action="" method="post">
 <input type="image" src="../images/buy.png" name="submit"  width="60"height="30"/>
</form>
</html>

Comment: the error meesage [02-Feb-2012 01:38:29] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in C:\www\IT3126_092810C\index.php on line 17